# Rails 4: Devise Invitable Unpermitted Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, devise, devise-invitable

I am using the [Devise Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) gem to invite users and after creating the user, I create a client with a `user_id` that is equal the `id` of the user that was just created

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :create_client

    def create_client
        new_client = Client.new()
        new_client.user_id = self.id
        new_client.save
    end
end
```

This works, but once I tried to add `location_id` to the parameters, I see:

```
Unpermitted parameter: location_id
```

Here is the new method with `location_id`

```
def create_client
    new_client = Client.new()
    new_client.user_id = self.id
    new_client.location_id = self.location_id
    new_client.save
end
```

I've read a lot of responses about this issue, but cannot seem to find a real solution to whitelist this parameter.  Does anyone have a method that works in Rails 4 with Devise 3.5

Answer (score 3):

It was crucial to whitelist the params for `:invite` and not just for `:accept_invitation`.  The following worked when I added it to my application_controller:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) << [:location_id]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:invite) << [:location_id]
end
```